# How can I add a comment in a multiline call chain in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

This is totally legal in ruby:

```
foo = {}
foo
  .key?('bar')
```

But this is a syntax error

```
foo = {}
foo
  # Why on earth can't I put a comment here?
  .key?('bar')
```

How can I document that specific method call? (In this contrived example the docs there are dumb, but in a 10 method call-chain documenting each one on a line is reasonable)

Comment: I had once made a feature request to allow that, but the Ruby core members seem to be negative on that (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7639).

Answer (score 4):

```
foo = {}
puts foo
  . # comment
  key?('bar')
```

It's not beautiful, but it works.

```
foo = {}
puts foo.
  # comment
  key?('bar')
```

is prettier, and still works.

Comment: The second style doesn't match the style guide I'm following :( https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: @PaulTarjan The style guide doesn't say so. It only says to be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

If you do indeed have a 10-method call chain, and need to document each call with a comment, then you might want to consider if your application design is reasonable.

In any case, you can use a backslash to create a multi-line call like you described:

```
foo = {}

foo \
  # This will work!
  .key?('bar')
#=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

[This doesn't solve your specific problem, but it's too long for a comment]

I usually write the comments on the same line, just after the method call I want to explain, e.g.:

```
10.times               # 0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9
  .map { |i| i * 3 }   # multiply by 3
  .select(&:odd?)      # keep odd numbers
  .reduce(:+)          # calculate sum
```

Comment: Or you could use lambdas to embed the comment right in the code: `multiply_by_three = lambda { |i| i * 3 }` and `.map(&multiply_by_three)` for example.